# UITextFields don't accept text in iOS6

Tags: uitextfield, ios6, uitextview, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an app built under iOS5. When I compiled the app with a few updates I discovered that no UITextFields in the app would acccept text input. The keyboard would appear, but typing would have no effect on the UITextField. My MainWindow was built using IB instead of via code.

Searching SO I discovered one possible problem was [self.window makeKeyAndVisible] missing from the application delegate, however, that did not solve the issue for me as I already had that in my application delegate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question to spread the knowledge...

I [found this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/731770#731770) post in the apple forums that provided the answer:

In interface builder select the MainWindow.xib file. Then select the viewController (in my case a TabBarController) and view the Attributes Inspector. There should be a field under View Controller which says "Title." I placed the name of my MainWindow xib (**"MainWindow_iPad"**)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an app developed for IOS 5 using XIB files.

Based on the Apple article mentioned above I simply enabled "Visible at launch" for both iPhone and iPad version of the MainWindow. No need to set any names or anything. 
The weird thing I saw before trying this was that if I showed an UIAlertView with an OK button , everything would work flawlessly after returning from that dialogue.

Thanks for the tip.